# What will be the time complexity of the function?

Tags: c++, string, recursion, time-complexity, backtracking

Today I was solving the word break problem but I was not able to calculate the time complexity of the implemented solution.

Here is the question:-
https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/word-break-part-2/0/

We have to find and print every sentence formed by the given string from the words contained in the dictionary provided in the test case.

> Example:- string = "snakesandladder", dictionary = ["snake", "snakes", "and", "sand", "ladder"].
>
> > A solution is ["snakes and ladder", "snake sand ladder"].

The function I implemented:-

```
set<vector<string>> res; `//stores all the sentences`
vector<string> v; `//stores all the words in a sentence`
helper(s, st, 0); `//function call`

void helper(string& s, unordered_set<string>& st, int i){
`//string s is the string and unordered_set<string> st is the dictionary.`
    if(i == s.size()){
        res.insert(v);
        return;
    }

    string temp = "";

    for(int k = i ; k < s.size() ; k++){
        temp += s[k];
        if(st.find(temp) != st.end()){
        v.push_back(temp);
        helper(s, st, k+1);
        v.pop_back(); `//Backtracking to find more solution`
        }
    }
}
```

My calculation says the time complexity should be O(n^n).

Comment: Why do you think it's `n^n`?

Comment: The complexity of `helper` will be a function of the size of `s` and the size of `st`. In the worst case you find _all_ of the words of `st` in `s`.

Comment: @ChrisMM The `for` loop will run `n` times(that is the length of the string) for a single call and after each successful lookup in the hash table, we will again continue this process for the remaining string(that is from k+1). In the worst case, we will be finding `1 to n` length of substrings in the dictionary. (That was my thinking)

Comment: @Botje Pardon me, but I am not getting you. But I think "In the worst case you find all of the words of `st` in `s`" this will lead to `O(n^n)`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the algorithm the worst case would be something like IIII trying to find the combination in the array: {I, I , I, I} which would mean you start with the I and then you got the three I's to check so you need 7 for the first one 7 for the second one and 7 for all of them, so thinking about your problem, (2n-1)*n in the worst case, so in this case the n was 4, in the case we got 28 calculations required if you wanted the big O notation, you would go O(n^2) do not know how you got N^N.... That's a truly massive number just saying that is suprising....

Comment: In backtracking, we try each and every combination available, and the same is happening here as the solution is using a backtracking algorithm. So, each and every combination results in `n^n`, that is how I got the upper bound.

Comment: It seems like you are doing something redundant then....